# Folding multiple templates for use as a template template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been experimenting with C++ template meta programming. For a particular problem I would like to be able to pass a template as a template argument.  As a minimal example, the following works:

```
template <class T> class H : public T {};

template <template <class> class TT>
class Assembler
{
public:
  using Type = TT<void>;
};

template <class T> using Folded = H<H<H<T> > >;
using ThisWorks = Assembler<Folded>::Type;
```

But, if I don't explicitly fold the other templates my program fails to compile:

```
using ThisDoesnt = Assembler<H<H<H> > >::Type;
```

Why does this second form not work (I can take a guess at why it doesn't work, but I would really appreciate a clear explaination)?  And, is there another alternative (or a more elegant way) for folding the other templates into a single template type?

Comment: Is `H<H<H>>` not also an invalid type, since it expects a type argument, yet you supply it with a template (the final `H`)?

Comment: @melak47 (second comment): Yes, this is what I did for `Assembler<Folded>`.  But is there a more elegant way?

Comment: @melak47 (first comment): I think this is probably the reason I get an error.  I'm passing a template as a type to the second last H.  But, why isn't this resolved automatically, is it ambiguous?

Comment: If all the template template parameters were variadic, you could do something [like this(coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f994cfc8ecf8dac) - but I don't know about "elegant" :)